# Select all words inside brackets (multiple matches)

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split a string in C#. I think it is better to see the next example:

```
string formula="[[A]]*[[B]]"
string split = Regex.Match(formula, @"\[\[([^)]*)\]\]").Groups[1].Value;
```

I would like to get a list of strings with the word contained between '[[' and ']]' so, in this case, I should get 'A' and 'B', but I am getting this: A]]*[[B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will match the **first** occurrence, and stop.  From the documentation:

> Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the Regex constructor.

You want [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get them all.  This regex will work:

```
\[\[(.+?)\]\]
```

It will capture anything between `[[` and `]]`

so your code could look like:

```
string formula = "[[A]]*[[B]]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(formula, @"\[\[(.+?)\]\]");

var results = (from Match m in matches select m.Groups[1].ToString()).ToList();

// results contains "A" and "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` matches as much as possible of the expression before it. Use a `*?` to match the smallest possible match.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#quantifiers

So your regex should be `@"\[\[([^)]*?)\]\]"`

Also, use `Regex.Matches` rather than `Regex.Match`, to get them all.